# Can a software developer/company be held liable for illegal acts done with their software?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, liability, hacking

If a software developer(s) / company creates software that can be used for hacking purposes but has "Terms of Use" that state it can not be used for an illegal activity. Can the creator(s) be held liable for an end users breach of those terms?

An example of this type of software is [Metasploit](https://www.metasploit.com/).

Relevant details about the software;

- Open Source
- Free
- No way to control its use

Comment: Does the software have any non-hacking applications?

Comment: No, it is an application strictly for security purposes.

Comment: I suspect that the answer is generally speaking **no** with some qualifications to establish that it is not part of a conspiracy with someone who uses it for hacking. But, establishing the negative is a non-trivial exercise and I'm not enough of an expert in that sub-field of law to say so with complete confidence.

Comment: More to the point, does it have any *legal* uses, like penetration testing?

Comment: Yes, the software's main purpose is for legal software penetration testing. But it can be used for illegal purposes.

Comment: Basically like some tool that could remotely detect unlocked front doors. The police could use this to warn the people living there, but there would be illegal uses as well :-)