# Can an individual be held responsible if their code is used maliciously?

Tags: internet, licensing, liability, freedom-of-speech, ethical-hacking

For a while now, I have been interested in viruses, backdoors, etc. As a result, I've started to tinker around with techniques on how to go undetectable for educational/personal purposes. I'd like to open source my code as a learning resource, however, I am worried that if someone were to actually use my code maliciously, I would be held responsible.

If I am to open source my code under a free license, what can I do to prevent myself from being blamed, can I write a guideline which specifies me as not responsible?

Comment: Most free licences have a fairly substantial disclaimer in them, wherein the licensor makes it clear that they take no responsibility for how others use their code.  Do you have a particular free licence in mind?  It will be much easier to answer your question in the context of a particular disclaimer.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/23659/can-a-software-developer-company-be-held-liable-for-illegal-acts-done-with-their

Comment: You don't identify a specific country's laws in your question and that is part of the fundamental problem of dong anything on the Internet. You could potentially be subjected to the laws of many countries, some of which could seek to hold you legally liable, while others do not.

Comment: It will also depend on whether the code in question can also be used for legitimate purposes, such as identification of security leaks in other software or the like.

Comment: And how likely it is to be used for a legitimate purpose, and if a judge takes it as a valid excuse. Which they likely won't. Legal disclaimers will be problematic. They may protect you if your software doesn't work as intended, but your problem is that the software _does_. work as intended.

Comment: @gnasher729 wouldn't that be a question of fact for a jury, in common law countries?

Comment: "wouldn't that be a question of fact" Duty is a question of law. Whether a duty was breached is a question of fact.

Comment: What if instead of code it was a gun ? Guns don't kill people, people with guns kill people

Comment: Related or possibly duplicate: [Can the Developer of a Program be penalized if it is used illegally?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/1049/can-the-developer-of-a-program-be-penalized-if-it-is-used-illegally).